# How can I run commands in bash script?

Tags: bash

How can I run commands in bash script?

This is my try:

```
#!/bin/bash

project_path = "/home/user/job/project";
venv = "home/user/job/virtualenv_project";

cd $venv;
source bin/activate;

cd $project_path;
python manage.py runserver;

echo "OK!"
```

but not working(project_path: not found, venv: not found etc.)

Comment: Remove spaces around `=`

Comment: sideNote: You don't need `;` at the end of every line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not allow spaces between assignments:

```
#!/bin/bash

project_path="/home/user/job/project";
venv="/home/user/job/virtualenv_project";

cd "$venv";
source bin/activate;

cd "$project_path";
python manage.py runserver;

echo "OK!"
```

Also it's good to always place arguments with variables inside double-quotes pairs to prevent unexpected word splitting and pathname expansion.

Comment: Thanks! There is only one problem yet: `t.sh: 7: t.sh: source: not found` in line `source bin/activate;`

Comment: `venv="home/user/job/virtualenv_project"` should probably read `venv="/home/user/job/virtualenv_project"`

Comment: @Flopp yes, copy/paste mistake on SO. Problem still exists.

Comment: Ok. With `. bin/activate` it works. Thanks.